JAXB files not generated automatically
POM.XML FILE:
please check if all the version dependencies are correct
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.soap.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>soap-course-management</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>soap-course-management</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</source>
                    </sources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

XSD FILE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://in28minutes.com/courses" 
xmlns:tns="http://in28minutes.com/courses" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    
    <xs:element name="GetCourseDetailsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "id" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>  
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="GetCourseDetailsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "CourseDetails" type="tns:CourseDetails"/>
            </xs:sequence>  
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:complexType name="CourseDetails">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    
</xs:schema>

I have tried to change the plugins version and yet so java file s getting generated
the xsd file is under src/main/resources
and also under a seperate folder under which the xsd file exists
